# Gulp Task for running Javascript over files

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'd like a gulp module that would let me modify the stream(s) by running a simple javascript function over the lines in the stream:

```
var runjs= require('gulp-runjs');
function grep(regexp) {<filter out lines not matching regexp>};
gulp.task('modify-sources', function () {
  return gulp.src("src/")
  .pipe(runjs(grep('...')))
  .pipe("dest/");
});
```

My specific need is to simulate grep on the gulp stream.  There is a gulp-grep-stream but that is only for filtering the files, not for modifying them. There is a gulp-shell module but I'd like to avoid that.

Is there one already?  Can it be done?  How would I do it without gulp but just raw node?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking for the same answer.

Comment: Nope, not yet. But on the other hand, I'm in the midst of migrating away from gulp to simple npm run scripts: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this plugin:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter

There is a method filter: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter#filterpattern-options

Seems that can do what you want.

Comment: I think this only includes/excludes files in the stream.  I.e. you can take a stream of both coffee and js files, filter the coffee files to run thru the compiler, the proceed with the original stream.  I want to actually change/edit the file contents in the stream.